# reading JSON file and manipulating it using dict()

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Im trying to solve this problem for a quite a long time now.

I have a Pokemon JSON file containing a several types such as lists and dicts of its characteristics. For example:
[Pokemon JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggr6y.jpg).

The input are the following:

```
path = 'datasets/pokedex.json'
name = 'Bulbasaur'
```

and the out put should be 67. Meaning I need to compute the "skills" of a given Pokemon.

```
"skills": {"egg": [133, 204, 174, 203, 202, 320, 580, 275, 437, 345, 267, 80, 438, 130, 124], "level_up": [33, 45, 73, 22, 77, 79, 36, 75, 230, 74, 38, 388, 235, 402], "tm": [92, 474, 237, 241, 113, 182, 219, 218, 76, 216, 104, 188, 263, 156, 213, 496, 497, 412, 148, 14, 447, 207, 214, 164, 249, 267, 590, 15, 70], "transfer": [20, 520, 282, 173, 331, 290, 445, 363], "tutor": [520]}, "type": ["\u8349", "\u6bd2"]}
```

The part of the JSON that contains "Bulbasaur" and the next Pokemon looks like this:

```
[{"base": {"Attack": 49, "Defense": 49, "HP": 45, "Sp.Atk": 65, "Sp.Def": 65, "Speed": 45}, "cname": "\u5999\u86d9\u79cd\u5b50", "ename": "Bulbasaur", "id": "001", "jname": "\u30d5\u30b7\u30ae\u30c0\u30cd", "skills": {"egg": [133, 204, 174, 203, 202, 320, 580, 275, 437, 345, 267, 80, 438, 130, 124], "level_up": [33, 45, 73, 22, 77, 79, 36, 75, 230, 74, 38, 388, 235, 402], "tm": [92, 474, 237, 241, 113, 182, 219, 218, 76, 216, 104, 188, 263, 156, 213, 496, 497, 412, 148, 14, 447, 207, 214, 164, 249, 267, 590, 15, 70], "transfer": [20, 520, 282, 173, 331, 290, 445, 363], "tutor": [520]}, "type": ["\u8349", "\u6bd2"]}, {"base": {"Attack": 62, "Defense": 63, "HP": 60, "Sp.Atk": 80, "Sp.Def": 80, "Speed": 60}, "cname": "\u5999\u86d9\u8349", "ename": "Ivysaur", "id": "002", "jname": "\u30d5\u30b7\u30ae\u30bd\u30a6", "skills": {"egg": [133, 204, 174, 203, 202, 320, 580, 275, 437, 345, 267, 80, 438, 130, 124], "level_up": [33, 45, 73, 45, 73, 22, 77, 79, 36, 75, 230, 74, 38, 388, 235, 76], "pre-evolution": [402], "tm": [92, 474, 237, 241, 113, 182, 219, 218, 76, 216, 104, 188, 263, 156, 213, 496, 497, 412, 148, 14, 447, 207, 214, 164, 249, 267, 590, 15, 70], "transfer": [20, 520, 282, 402, 173, 331, 290, 445, 363], "tutor": [520]}, "type": ["\u8349", "\u6bd2"]}, ... ]
```

```
path = 'datasets/pokedex.json'

name = "Bulbasaur"

def compute_pokemon_skills(path: str, name: str) -> int:
    
    with open(path) as path:
        pokedex = json.load(path)
        
    ...
    
compute_pokemon_skills(name,path)
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why the output should be 67? What is the formula?

Comment: its the len of list that is inside the skill section

Comment: for example egg: = len([133, 204, 174, 203, 202, 320, 580, 275, 437, 345, 267, 80, 438, 130, 124]) = 15